# Centriole genes Knock-out Experiment in Common experimental animals?

Tags: genetics, molecular-biology, cell-biology, molecular-genetics

Anyone know of any experiments that have knocked out the genes for producing centrioles in a worm, mouse, fish, fly or whatever animal? Are the genes for centrioles even identified? It has been shown that centrosomes form with out centrioles so I'm curious how lack of centrioles would effect the system of an animal as a whole.

Answer (score 1):

One of the chief components of centrosome is γ-Tubulin.

In this [study](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/15893303) the authors have reported the effect of γ-Tubulin knockout in mice.

Quoting the abstract:

> Gamma-tubulin regulates the nucleation of microtubules, but knowledge
>   of its functions in vivo is still fragmentary. Here, we report the
>   identification of two closely related gamma-tubulin isoforms, TUBG1
>   and TUBG2, in mice, and the generation of TUBG1- and TUBG2-deficient
>   mice. TUBG1 was expressed ubiquitously, whereas TUBG2 was primarily
>   detected in the brain. The development of TUBG1-deficient (Tubg1-/-)
>   embryos stopped at the morula/blastocyst stages due to a
>   characteristic mitotic arrest: the mitotic spindle was highly
>   disorganized, and disorganized spindles showed one or two pole-like
>   foci of bundled MTs that were surrounded by condensed chromosomes.
>   TUBG2 was expressed in blastocysts, but could not rescue the TUBG1
>   deficiency. By contrast, TUBG2-deficient (Tubg2-/-) mice were born,
>   grew, and intercrossed normally. In the brain of wild-type mice, TUBG2
>   was expressed in approximately the same amount as TUBG1, but no
>   histological abnormalities were found in the Tubg2-/- brain. These
>   findings indicated that TUBG1 and TUBG2 are not functionally
>   equivalent in vivo, that TUBG1 corresponds to conventional
>   gamma-tubulin, and that TUBG2 may have some unidentified function in
>   the brain.

Another important gene is pericentrin. Fibroblasts from pericentrin knockout mice show abnormal spindles during mitosis have been [studied](http://jcb.rupress.org/content/188/2/181.full).

> In agreement with a model in which pericentrin is required for correct
>   spindle orientation, fibroblasts isolated from PCNT knockout mice show
>   a significant increase in cells with disrupted astral microtubules and
>   misoriented spindles (Fig. 2; unpublished data; Zheng, G., personal
>   communication). Spindle misorientation is shown by an increase in the
>   angle formed by the pole-to-pole spindle vector and the cell–substrate
>   adhesion plane in pericentrin knockout compared with wild-type
>   fibroblasts.

Apparently both *TUBG* and *PCNT* deletions (individually) are not lethal.